# does `yo generator-angular-fullstack` have generators for backend api?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using `yo generator-angular-fullstack` and I see generators for angular client app, but nothing for backend. Is there a way to generate api routes and controllers and mongoose models that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Could be too late but check out the guide on [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

What you are looking for is called angular-fullstack:endpoint.